# How do you add a flyout message to a WPF button using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Below is my xaml for a button I would like to have a message fly out from:

```
    <Button  x:Name="ClearButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Width="90" Margin="0,0,0,0"
             Click="ClearButton_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-15,0,0,5" >
            <Image Source="{StaticResource EraseButtonImageKey}" 
                   Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="20" Width="20" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="0,0,0,0"  Margin="2,0,0,0">Clear</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

I would like to have a small single line of text fly out when a mouse pointer moves over a button in WPF. For example, if you are using the Chrome browser a small line of text fly's out when you move your cursor over the back arrow at the top which says "click to go back".  How can I have a message like that pop out when I move a mouse pointer over a WPF button? The message I want displayed for my button would be "Removes all text from the results window."

Thanks in advance.

---- UPDATE FEB 9, 2019 ------

Thanks to the comment from the.doc I updated my code to the following which now gives me the result I was looking for:

```
    <Button  x:Name="ClearButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Width="90" Margin="0,0,0,0"
             Click="ClearButton_Click">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-15,0,0,5" >
            <Image Source="{StaticResource EraseButtonImageKey}" 
                   Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="20" Width="20" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="0,0,0,0"  Margin="2,0,0,0">Clear</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Removes all text from the result window</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Have you looked into tooltip control?

Comment: Thank you. That works great. I never noticed that feature was part of the Button control.

Comment: Post what you learned as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution to the problem I had by using the Button.ToolTip feature which The.Doc suggested:

```
<Button  x:Name="ClearButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Width="90" Margin="0,0,0,0"
         Click="ClearButton_Click">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-15,0,0,5" >
        <Image Source="{StaticResource EraseButtonImageKey}" 
               Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="20" Width="20" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Padding="0,0,0,0"  Margin="2,0,0,0">Clear</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Removes all text from the result window</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```